# Tabs to change view of webpart

Tags: 2010

SharePoint 2010

Current setup: Webpart page with a Calendar webpart.

Requirement: Be able to change the view of the calendar dynamically(?) without having to leave the page.  Basically, I'm looking for a way to add "tabs" or links on the page so that a user can click on it and the view in the Calendar webpart will change or it will apply filter values to the calendar.

Example: user can click on "Meetings" and the calendar will show only items with that category

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [EasyTabs](http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/pages/easytabs.aspx) plugin. This will allow you to create separate views in separate web parts with your specific filters and show them in a tab format.